# Model comparison: segmented GLM and GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model-comparison, segmented-regression

I have two model comparison questions:

*First comparison:*
I have a GLM model and a segmented GLM model. both models have the same dependent and independent variables. The only difference is that we assume a segmented (piecewise linear) relationship for one of the independent variables in the segmented regression.

Now I'd like to compare these two models. So the first question is, are GLM and segmented GLM nested? What tests should I use to compare them?

*Second comparison:*
A special case of segmented regression allows me to control the slope of the left segment. I could constrain the left slope to be zero. So it's a "flat-then-decrease/increase" type of relationship. How do I compare this special case with the regular segmented regression that has no constraint on the slopes?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

edit: the R package "segmented" developed by Dr.Vito M. R. Muggeo is used.

Comment: When you refer to piecewise linear, do mean the linear trendline is continuous or are breakpoint discontinuities allowed?